# c# обращение к переменной bool из другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс **newgen** с переменными bool, перекреплен к объектам, а эти объекты лежат в массиве другого класса **section**. Как правильно обратиться к
переменным up, down, left, right, starta в классе section ?

```
public class newgen : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool up, down, left, right, starta;
    }
```

---

```
public class section : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject [] WALLS;
    void Start(){
        gen ();
    }
    void gen (){
        for (int index = 0; index < WALLS.Length; index++){
            newgen chose = new newgen ();
            chose.starta = chose;
            Debug.Log(chose);   
            if (chose == true){
                Instantiate(WALLS [0], transform.position, transform.rotation);
                break;
               }
            }
        }
  }
```

Debug.Log(chose); показывает null, а так же предупреждение для этой строки newgen chose = new newgen ();

You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all

Comment: Проблема забивания гвоздей микроскопом, опишите, что вы хотите сделать. В Unity нельзя просто так создавать `MonoBehaviour`, они обязательно должны идти в связке с `GameObject`'ом.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это вообще компилируется? Что это такое: `chose.starta = chose;`? `bool = GameObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как правильно обратиться к переменным up, down, left, right, starta в классе section ?

1. (неправильный) Сделать класс newgen статическим и отвязать наследование от MonoBehaviour и тогда обращатся к нему с любого места любого класса напрямую: `newgen.up`
2. (правильный) Оставить класс динамическим, но передавать инстанс даного класса во все обьекты которым нужно иметь доступ к даному обьекту. И тогда обращатся к инстансу класса:
   `newgenInstance.up`

Comment: Изначальный написан абсолютно неправильно и без малейшего понимания, как работает Unity. Вы уверены, что ваши подсказки что-то дадут автору?

Comment: ну... ответ на заданный вопрос я дал. И он -- обьективно верный и максимально понятно написанный.... Не представляю как можно написать более понятно :)

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, что именно хочет автор. Вас не смущает создание `MonoBehaviour` через `new`? Вас не смущает `chose.starta = chose;`? И вас, наконец, не смущает проверка существования объекта сразу после создания этого объекта? Никто не спорит, что ваш ответ правильный, вопрос в том, этот ли вопрос задавал автор на самом деле?